# Unable To Log In Through Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

[See this question for details of troubleshooting I've been stepping through (I did answer 2, which didn't work - it was a corrupt master file).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617402/the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion)

In configuration manager, I changed to a `Built-in account`, to solve the problem in the above linked question.  That didn't work.  When I realized it was a corrupt master file and replaced everything, the issue of starting SQL Server worked.  Now I can't log into it.  Originally, SQL Server Express has a default account that I've never touched in the radio option `This account:` and underneath that `Account Name:` (it appears to be `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`).  Ignorantly, I've never set a password because I use Windows Authentication when logging in and from what I knew, the password was my normal Windows account.  In addition, I've tried setting up a backup account as a sysadmin SQL authentication login, but it never works on logging in and after hours of research a while ago, I gave up on this (different issue, but never identified why setting up another use for sysadmin didn't work).

I've tried using the below:

`NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER`

I've also tried the options in the `Built-in account` **Network Service**, **Local System**, and **Local Service** and none of these recognize my built in Windows credentials, which is very scary (my other SQLExpress does).
This doesn't work with my normal Windows password and I know the default account had `$` characters in it, so I don't think that was the default.  When setting up SQL Server, what default account does it use?

**Update**

It appears to be this account => `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`.  However, my windows authentication still fails.  This would imply that SQL Server set a default password for the above account when I installed, yet somehow my normal Windows Authentication username and password was able to login.  I have no idea how that happened, but this appears to be the case as the Windows Auth password for the above account won't allow me to login when I log in with Windows Auth.

Comment: I installed it logged in as myself and the service is running under my account. Not sure if this was something I specified in the install but this goes to show, it could be anything. I would look at your services to know for sure.

Comment: @Steve Verifying => `services.msc`?  I see the logon and hashed password for the `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`, but the problem is that the password may not be accurate if it's not using my normal Windows authentication.  It will allow me to enter any password I want for that account, I just will get an error when logging in.  One thing I know, it's not using my Windows password, but I wonder how the default got set to something else?

Comment: Is your SQL instance set to SQL Server and Windows Authentication under Properties, Security?

Comment: I know this is a bit old but when services are running as NT Service\<accountname> this is the per-service SID and the OS manages the password itself. More information can be found here: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#New_Accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#New_Accounts). However, this doesn't solve the problem and I assume for this issue the original poster created their login as a sysadmin during installation.